# Sending user to another application (share/ complete using) using phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Sending user to another application (share/ complete using) using phonegap

I need to send user to another application . Is there any plugin available. 
like eg: when I click on email ..it has to show all mail supporting applications in user mobile.

Note: need to provide support for both ios as well as android

Comment: Only email or you need for other apps too??

Comment: I need other apps too .. I had given 1 senario

Comment: Ah! I think you'll need different functionality for different subject.Not sure though. For email only, I can suggest you this https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

Comment: @divya find any solution for this question. i have also do same think.but i can't find any solution